# Wii Fit data format?

Tags: wii

So the boss just came buy to tell me he's buying a Wii + Wii Fit for the office. At first I'm thinking this is awesome, we're getting a Wii. But, we're a pretty fit group, why do we need the Wii Fit too? Of course, I opened my stupid mouth to ask that very question when I should have been basking in the glory of the moment. sigh...the work never ends...

Apparently the Wii Fit saves some sort of data to an SD card and he wants to know if we can access that data. A quick search yielded nearly nothing, except a note that the data is stored as a text file, but in Japanese. The boss is still out shopping so I can't yet see for myself.

Has anyone tried to get at the Wii Fit data? Any luck?

Comment: There are definitely worse things you could be doing! ;)

Comment: Like "Generating Test Data"? :P

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to decode the WiiFit save data.

Once the WiiFit savedata is stored to a SD card it will be named private\wii\title\RFNP\data.bin (for pal) or private\wii\title\RFNN\data.bin (for NTSC)

This is a standardized Wii format that all games use and it is described at http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Savegame_Files

Once you have decrypted the header and data area with he keys from http://hackmii.com/2008/04/keys-keys-keys/ you will find that data.bin contain the files:

```
RPFitCap.dat
RPHealth.dat
RPWiiFit.dat
```

These files are unencrypted, but I have not analyzed their content more then just to be able to extract weight and bmi data for my own Mii.

I have a really dirty vb6 class that produces a CSV file with dates and weight but its faaaaaar away from any kind of release.

Heres some of my extracted data:

```
15.11.2008 13:18:00;92
16.11.2008 15:30:00;91,1
17.11.2008 19:02:00;91,3
18.11.2008 08:23:00;90,8
19.11.2008 07:20:00;90,5
20.11.2008 09:34:00;90,5
21.11.2008 09:32:00;91,1
22.11.2008 09:11:00;91,3
23.11.2008 10:25:00;91,6
24.11.2008 10:36:00;91,2
25.11.2008 10:37:00;91,4
26.11.2008 13:40:00;90,8
27.11.2008 10:45:00;91,2
28.11.2008 11:32:00;91,4
29.11.2008 13:09:00;91
30.11.2008 13:18:00;90
01.12.2008 12:38:00;90,1
02.12.2008 13:16:00;91,2
03.12.2008 10:34:00;91,2
04.12.2008 12:06:00;91
05.12.2008 13:05:00;91,2
06.12.2008 16:28:00;90,3
07.12.2008 14:03:00;90,9
08.12.2008 12:38:00;91,3
09.12.2008 14:18:00;90,4
10.12.2008 13:43:00;90,5
11.12.2008 13:36:00;90,5
12.12.2008 14:15:00;90,3
13.12.2008 14:17:00;89,9
14.12.2008 10:42:00;90
```

./Al

Comment: Can I see that vb6 class. I would like to build up on it as a hobby :D

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use this info to create a table of where the data is stored in the Wii Fit savegame files.

There is more detail in the following blog post: http://jansenprice.com/blog?id=9-Extracting-Data-from-Wii-Fit-Plus-Savegame-Files

```
File FitPlus0.dat
-----------------
Byte Offset | Length | Description
-----------------------------------
0x0         | 8      | RPHE0000 (header)
0x8         | 22     | Name of Mii
0x1E        | 1      | Unknown
0x1F        | 1      | Height (in cm)
0x20        | 4      | Date of birth (stored in BCD: e.g. 1980 0228)
0x24        |        | Unknown
0x95        |        | Dates with data (rowlen=10)
0x35CF      |        | Start of some other section (unknown)
0x38A1      |        | Body Test measurement data section (rowlen=21)
  +0        | 4      | Date (in bitfield format)
  +4        | 2      | Weight (in kg * 10)
  +6        | 2      | BMI (* 100)
  +8        | 2      | Balance percent (* 10)
  +10       | 2      | simple value 4 ??
  +12       | 1      | extended 1 ??
  +13       | 1      | extended 2 ??
  +14       | 1      | extended 3 ??
  +15       | 1      | extended 4 ??
  +16       | 2      | extended 5 ??
  +18       | 1      | extended 6 ??
  +19       | 1      | extended 7 ??
0x9288      | 1      | Last byte of profile
```